# How to show field in snippet?

Tags: entities

I use PHP filter module, and write this in other field in my node:

```
<?php
  $node = node_load(52);
  $field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'myfield');
  print $field;
?>
```

It doesnt work. 
And how i can load id for node?

Comment: To get get current page node id you can use " print arg(1) "

Answer (score 2):

field_view_field returns a renderable array for the field value. So you should use render() function:

```
<?php
  $node = node_load(52);
  $field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'myfield');
  print render($field);
?>
```